# CodeIgniter Twitter API (Elliot Haughin's) capturing any URL get parameters with "oauth_token" in it

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

Seems a little strange.

I am using CodeIgniter with [Elliot Haughin's Twitter library](http://www.haughin.com/code/twitter/). It's an excellent API by the way.

However, I autoload this library in "autoload.php" in the config folder and I noticed ANY URL that has "oauth_token" URL parameter is captured by this library.

For example, when I type

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.php/controller?oauth_token=1
```

Then it throws up an error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: libraries/Tweet.php
Line Number: 205
```

I went through the library and found that the following constructor calling a method that checks the GET parameters.

```
class tweetOauth extends tweetConnection {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    ..
    ..
    ..
    $this->_checkLogin();
  }
```

and the method "_checkLogin()" does the following

```
private function _checkLogin()
{
  if ( isset($_GET['oauth_token']) )
  {
    $this->_setAccessKey($_GET['oauth_token']);
    $token = $this->_getAccessToken();
    $token = $token->_result;
    ...
    ...
```

What would be the best way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have to autoload it? Can't you just load it in your twitter controller/method?

Comment: I guess I don't HAVE TO. And I tried NOT autoloading, and it works fine. But my question is in how this plugin can be tweaked so that it doesn't capture all the "$_GET['oauth_token']" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have oauth_token in the querystring if you're not checking for a valid oauth_token? 
I'm assuming at some point you want to state that a oauth_token has been set and you're just using oauth_token=1 as the parameter?

The library is set to always test against oauth_token, and it's not really a feasible tweak to do it any other way if you're autoloading it. You'd need a whitelist/blacklist of controllers (and maybe methods) it runs on, which pretty much defeats the point of autoloading.

If REALLY need to use oauth_token=1, you could just change it to

```
if ( isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && $_GET['oauth_token']!==1)
```

If you were using more than one value for oauth_token (or if your worry is that you can trigger an error by appending oauth_token=X to a URL) you could try and use a regex instead, assuming that all oauth_tokens follow a pattern (32 characters long etc).

Alternatively you could also probably just exit/return false depending on what is returned in $token = $this->_getAccessToken(). Depends what happens elsewhere in the code. Looks like returning false should just work.

Comment: @apermantus, oauth_token=1 was just a sample value I put in there, as any oauth_token value I give, this plugin was capturing it. The reason why this is causing a problem is because I'm using another library that uses oauth to connect to another API.

Comment: Right; in that case then depending on your need, the easiest thing to do is to either a) only include this library manually or b) exclude certain controllers/methods using if ($this->router->class!="other_api") in class tweetOauth depending on what makes most sense.